# How to add particular css classes to the checkboxes generated by a django MultipleChoiceField?

Tags: python, django

I have a django form that renders an `MultipleChoiceField`. In the `__init__` part I define the choices for my field as a tuple.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'flat'}))

    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        datas = Mymodel.objects.all()
        datas.sort(key=itemgetter('foo', 'bar'))
        datas_grouped = groupby(datas, key=itemgetter('foo'))
        choices = tuple()
        for foo, items in datas_grouped:
            items = tuple((i.get('label'), i.get('label')) for i in list(items))
            choices += ((foo, items),)

        self.fields["my_field"].choices = choices
```

The checkboxes are rendered as this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_field" value="Baz" class="flat" id="id_my_field_0_0">
```

I would like to render some checkboxes with a particular css class. The goal is to be able to target them in javascript to make grouped selections.

How can I access each checkbox individually, in python, in order to add a class?